# Facebook Login Button Android in Eclipse

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

In activity_mainfest.xml

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical">

 <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    /> 
    </LinearLayout>
```

In AndroidMainfest.xml ,i have set permission

[image]

But it gives the above error display in screenshot.

**The Application stopped unexpectedly.Please try again.Force Close**

Comment: did you added add necessary library ? and it must be in same workspace with your project

Comment: you add facebook sdk in your project?

Comment: yes i have added facebook sdk as a libary project in eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the updated screenshot, it seems you are missing the following permission from your `AndroidManifest.xml`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Answer (score 0):

Have you include facebook dependency libraries to the project? It's neccesary.

PD: I recommend you to use android studio for android apps.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when your project can't find the library files; it usually mean you haven't referenced it correctly.

If you have downloaded the facebook library, go to file->import -> Existing Android Code into workspace. 
Select the facebook library. Now right click on the facebook project, and select properties. Ensure the "is library" checkbox is ticked under the Android tab.

Finally, right click on your project, go to the Android tab and click add next the library button. Select the facebook library and all dependencies should be set up.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But when i ticked "is library" checkbox ,it gives error like Android library projects can;t be launched.

Comment: Please can you edit the question and add the logtrace?

Comment: @maulika The **Facebook SDK** project should be marked as a library, **not** your app

Comment: @Ed George i have marked Facebook SDK as library.but no success

Comment: @Matt Boyle i have edited question and attach screenshot

Comment: @maulika The error you posted is no longer related to the Facebook SDK issue, please consider marking this question resolved and making a new question.